# Relativistic Momentum in One Frame

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, momentum

34. (I) What is the momentum of a proton traveling at v = 0.75c?

This problem requires a simple substitution. Using the equation
$\ p_{rel} = m*u * (1/\sqrt(1 - v^2/c^2))$, where $v$ is the speed of a frame and $u$ the speed of a particle in that moving frame,

we let both $v \ \& \ u = 0.75c$

I have two questions?

1) In this problem, what justfies our setting v to u; letting the frame's speed be the particle's speed.

2) If there were a frame in which the proton moved (a proton moves on a moving airplane, for example), would v = frameSpeed + particleSpeed.

As in: we have a plane moving at 0.1 c and a proton at 0.6c. Is v, the frame speed, effectively 0.7c then?

---

After a comment by John Rennie

the link to the relavistic addition of velocities clarified that, for an observer, the velocity of the object moving in the moving frame can't be clasically understood. Even so, why would an observer substitute the velocity they perceive for $u$ in the equation $\ p_{rel} = m*u * (1/\sqrt(1 - v^2/c^2))$

Shouldn't **any** observer, in any frame, use proper particle speed (what the frame in question reports for speed) and the frame speed. Thus, in the example above,

"we have a plane moving at 0.1 c and a proton at 0.6c"

isn't the substitution $v = 0.1c$ and $u = 0.6c$

---

**The resolution to this question**

Relavistic momentum is **not** $\ p_{rel} = m*u * (1/\sqrt(1 - v^2/c^2))$

but $\ p_{rel} = m*u * (1/\sqrt(1 - u^2/c^2))$

Notice the difference in the square root term. Any observer calculating momentum for an object should substitute for u what **they** believe the object's speed to be. This requires you to use velocity addition equations (see John Rennie's comment)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure I have fully grasped what you are asking. The equation is for calculating the momentum of the proton in the inertial frame of the observer i.e. the frame velocity is zero by definition. The only thing moving is the proton, at a speed $v$.

If, as in your question 2, you have a different frame then the speed of the proton in that frame is given by the formula for the [relativistic addition of velocities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Velocity-addition_formula#Special_theory_of_relativity) - you cannot simply add the velocities.

Comment: "frame velocity is zero by definition" I thought so as well. And consequently: that the equation would ultimately be p = mv. My answer disagrees for some reason. I've included a screenshot. As for question #2, please see my edit.